# Как задать собственный разделитель для хлебных крошек?

Tags: css

В общем название отражает вопрос. Как это сделать? Нужно задать разделитель в виде двоеточия. Пытался через `css` указывая `content: ':'`, вроде разделяет, **но** это разделение смотрится едва заметно, блеклый цвет и сами двоеточия прижаты к элементу списка, т.е. я не могу их позиционировать. Так вот, как мне довести до ума? или подскажите другой способ.
**пример**

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {content: ':';padding: 0;}
.breadcrumb > li:after {content: '';display: block;position: absolute;top: -3px;
right: -5px;
width: 26px;}
```

Так вот `padding` ни на что не влияет, не знаю почему.

Comment: Почему не можете позиционировать?

Comment: Приведите пример кода того, что не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
ul>li:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}
ul>li:before {
  content: ':';
  margin: -2px 5px 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #f00;
}
ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">breadcrumb</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">breadcrumb</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">breadcrumb</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```